# Manually mark imported photo as selected in media library

Tags: javascript, media-library

Using image/attachment ID I want to manually set image to be selected in media library in javascript.

[image]

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selection = wp.media.frame.state().get('selection');
var attachment = wp.media.attachment(image.ID);
selection.add(attachment);
```

Comment: could you add some details for the OP on how or where to use this?

Comment: @rudtek I answered myself :)

Comment: The idea is if someone else has the same problem then they can use the answer (yours or otherwise) to help them solve.  More detail helps. (and encourages upvotes etc).  Another programmer may not understand where you put this code etc.